# Putting a repeating value into a column

Tags: r

I feel dumb asking this but here goes.  I have a list of numbers but I want to combine it with date.

for instance:

```
list1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
list2 <-c("2009-01-01")
list3 <-cbind(list2, list1)
```

I want the SAME date listed the same number of times as there are data points and then combined with the data points.

```
date                number
"2009-01-01"          1
"2009-01-01"          2
"2009-01-01"          3
"2009-01-01"          4
"2009-01-01"          5
```

When I try to run the above code I get the message about lengths not matching. Any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand; it works for me....  You may want to try a data.frame rather than a matrix (which `cbind` produces).  Also, avoid calling things that aren't `list`s "list".  It just gets confusing since a list is an R data type.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Edited to make my data frame comment more descriptive.*

How about using `rep`?

```
list1 <- 1:5
list2 <- rep("2009-01-01",length(list1))
list3 <- cbind(list2, list1)
```

although R's recycling rules ought to give you your desired output regardless. Also, are you sure you don't want a data frame:

```
list3 <- data.frame(date = list2, number = list1)
```

since `cbind` will in your case produce a character matrix, which, since matrices must only be of a single type.

Answer (score 4):

`cbind` will return a dataframe if one of the arguments is a dataframe.  In that case, it simply acts as a wrapper for `data.frame` [see `?cbind`].

In the other answers and comments where the users said that `cbind` did work and it created a matrix, they left out that the matrix was a character matrix and the numbers were coalesced to character strings.  You probably didn't want that.

One solution, not presented yet, is to do this:

```
vector1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
vector2 <- c("2009-01-01");
cbind(data.frame(date = vector2), number = vector1);
```

This creates a dataframe because the first argument is a dataframe.

But, I think the best, and the one that really shows that you know what you want is to call `data.frame` directly:

```
data.frame(date = vector2, number = vector1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason I'm posting despite seeing that you thought another answer was "perfect" is that `cbind` returns a matrix, which since you had one vector that was 'character', is entirely of type 'character'.

```
> str(list3)
 chr [1:5, 1:2] "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "list2" "list1
```

It would be better when one is working with data of mixed type (dates and numeric) to use a data.frame. It has the addition feature that you don't even need to use rep() since argument recycling will repeat automagically:

```
> data.frame(dt = as.Date("2009-01-01"), l1 = list1)
          dt l1
1 2009-01-01  1
2 2009-01-01  2
3 2009-01-01  3
4 2009-01-01  4
5 2009-01-01  5
```

Comment: Good point.  I have some experience with r and I still struggle to remember the  various data type handling.  Thanks for the reminder.